# Extract Structure definitions from executable

Tags: debugging, elf, debug-symbols, readelf

I need to extract structure definitions from an executable. How can I do that?
I read we can do it using ELF, but not sure how to do this. Any help here?

Comment: if your binary has debuginfo, just use gdb `ptype` command

Comment: my approach for getting a struct from raw memory is to read documentation of function parameters, and start from there, most functions  params for structs points to a memory address.

Answer (score 3):

> I read we can do it using ELF, but not sure how to do this.

What you *probably* read is that **if** a binary contains debug info, **then** the types of variables, structures, and great many other kinds of info can be extracted from that binary.

This isn't specific to `ELF`: many other executable formats (such as `COFF`) allow for embedding of debugging info as well.

Further, the *format* of that debugging info is different between different platforms. Some of the common UNIX ones are `DWARF` and `STABS` (with `DWARF` being more recent and much more powerful).

If you have an `ELF` binary, and you suspect that it may contain `DWARF` debug info, you can decode it using `readelf -wi a.out` (be prepared for there to be a *lot* of info, if any is present at all). `objdump -g` can be used to decode `STABS` (recent `objdump` versions can decode `DWARF` as well).

Or, as suggested by tristan, you can load the executable into GDB and use `info types` and `ptype` commands.

If the binary doesn't contain debug info, then DrPrItay's answer is correct: you can't *easily* recover structure definitions from it. However, you *still* can recover them by using reverse-engineering techniques. For example, many struct definitions used by the `Wine` project ([example](http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/include/accctrl.h)) were obtained by such techniques.

Answer (score -1):

As much as I know, you can't. c / c++ programs are not like java, structs dont gain a symbol. Their just definitions for your compiler about how to align and pack variables within stack frames or some other memory (struct data members). For example unlike java you dont have what resembles class loading when loading shared objects's (no header file included within your c program )  you can only load global variables and functions. Defining a struct is much as creating some data type, it's definition should be only present for compilation, you dont get a symbol within the symtable for `int` or `char` then why should you for some struct? It simply makes no sense. Symbols aee soley meant for objects that your compiler doesn't recognize during compilation - link time/load time/run time

Comment: "As much as I know, you can't." -- you have much still to learn.